# HttpURLConnection cURL GET method and RequestProperty

Tags: java, json, rest, curl

I am having trouble getting some information from Twitch.TV API v3 (https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/streams.md).

They have an example to make the request:

> curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' \
>   -X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/test_channel

But everytime i call the link from the browser or directly from java, i get content from both versions (v3 and v2) but my java objects are prepared only for v3, then i got an exception.

The question is, how can i cURL like that in JAVA?
i tried this:

```
  url = new URL(type.getValue() + param);
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  conn.setDoInput(true);
  conn.setDoOutput(false);
  conn.setUseCaches(false);
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
  //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json");

  //System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
  //System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());

  // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();

  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    stb.append(line);
  }
```

Even with the method GET and the RequestProperty the result wasn't different, one thing that i noticed is that it now comes ONLY in V2, never in V3...

Any ideas?? thanks!

"solved" as shown in the comment below.

Comment: Problem solved, there was a bug in Twitch API, here is the issue track: https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/issues/132 and the code above worked correctly after the fix, sorry for the useless question, at least this works for someone who can't find how to set headers for html requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, there was a bug in Twitch API, here is the issue track:
http://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/issues/132
and the code above (my question) worked correctly after the fix,sorry for the useless question,
at least this works for someone who can't find how to set headers for html requests.